# What is a the name for a javascript array mixed with an object literal?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, object-literal

I'm quite new to Javascript, and I'm trying to develop an application using Google Maps.

I came across this class in Google Maps called `GeocoderResults`, with [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

In the documentation, it says that a `results` object is passed in the following form:

[image: Geocoder Form]

However, in all the material I've read and searched on Javascript, the closest thing this looks like is an `object literal`. The problem is it lacks an equals sign and it's name, `results[]` represents an array!

It must be some type of structure I've never seen before.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: It's just multiple nested objects and arrays. Have a look at an example of a real response and you'll understand the given docu.

Comment: How can I see a real response? For example, when I use `alert`s with the example Google Maps provides, it just prints `[object object]`

Comment: Either use `console.log()` and have a look in your developer console (better approach) or use `alert( JSON.stringify( result ) )` instead of a plain `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

This itself is not an object literal. It is merely a type information about what fields the result (which will be an actual object literal) will contain and how they look. Each of the fields is explained below that in the documentation.

The actual result will look like

```
{
    results: [
        {
            types: [
                "…",
                …
            ],
            formatted_address: "…",
            address_components: [
                {…},
                …
            },
            partial_match: false,
            geometry: {…}
        },
        …
    ],
    status: "…"
}
```

Comment: Ah, so it's essentially an object that has one item - an array called `results`.

Comment: Actually there also is a `status` property in the object. Just open your network inspector and check out an example response.